Sign in User after password is set
I have made an authentication gateway in my Android app (Kotlin)  through phone OTP using Firebase auth for sign-up and I want to sign in the same user through email and password, but I want to store the password later in the app after OTP sign up and use it for verification during sign in through same password.
Is there any way?

So do you need to have a single account or two different accounts for each type of authentication?

I need to have single account

In your last comment, you specified that you need to have a single account when you authenticate your users in Firebase with phone, and email/password. This means that when you want to use multiple Firebase authentication providers, you have to link them, so both phone and email/password accounts will be treated as a single account. For more information, I recommend you read the official documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking


Hi , I have looked into this but I want the user who has signed up through OTP to setup its password later when editing its profile and use that password to authenticate using email and password .

You can create a Firebase Account with a phone, and let the user choose a password that can be later used, but in order to use the authentication with email and password, you have to link the two accounts. In this, the user will be able to sign in with the chosen email and password.
